# What will happen when I draw too much current from a voltage regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

Let's say that I have a 5V, 150mA rated LDO whose input is connected to ideal voltage source with infinite amount of current drive capability.

Just to make the matter simple, what will happen if I connect an resistor smaller than 5/0.15 = 33 Ohm from its output to ground?

which of the following two will happen?

Will it permanently damage the LDO or the voltage output on the voltage regulator drop?

The regulator I am looking at is NCP551 Series

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: Information readily available in the data sheet. Question should be closed.

Answer (score 7):

As the [datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCP551-D.PDF) says:

[image]

The output current will be no more than Vout/R, but could be as high as 600mA for a short circuit.

If you cause the chip to overheat you will shorten its life, however it will usually shut down to protect itself at (typically) 160°C junction temperature. This is above the  maximum operating junction temperature of 150°C, indicating that you can expect some permanent damage. For example, the output voltage may drift or it may fail earlier than it would otherwise.